# Error while exporting csv data in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, csv

I have a huge set of data that is exported as csv in my web application.

I will simplify it for easy understanding. Let me say that I have the following text:

```
text,value
Sample text,This is the #1 site for answers
```

Its been formatted and ready for exporting as csv. Before that, I encode it using `encodeURI()` and then I assign it to the `href` attribute of an anchor tag as:

```
data:text/csv;utf-8,<the encoded string goes here>
```

The issue is that only when the string contains a #, only in Firefox, the entire CSV file is not downloaded. Only upto the row previous to the row containing # is downloaded. This happens only in firefox.

If I replace the # with an alphabet, everything is fine. The hash character upsets the download - only in firefox.

Comment: This looks like a Firefox bug. That said, I don't think `encodeURI` is what you want, this is UTF-8 text, not a URI. As a workaround, you could try using base64 encoding, that might hide the `#` from Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `encodeURIComponent` function.